# Solr OutOfMemoryException with custom HttpClient connections

Tags: java, solr, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a Java web application that indexes data in Solr 4.4 using the Solrj API and also queries Solr directly using its HTTP API. My webapp and Solr each run in their own instance of Tomcat on the same server. I just changed my application's HttpSolrServer from using the default `HttpClient` configuration to use a custom configured singleton instance (Spring bean) of SystemDefaultHttpClient using a PoolingClientConnectionManager.

My problem is that my Solr webapp keeps throwing OutOfMemoryExceptions every couple days. I can see with `netstat` and `lsof` that my application maintains sockets to Solr in a CLOSE_WAIT state after making requests to Solr, which probably indicates I am not releasing idle connections correctly. However, the Solr process does not appear to keep any sockets open from its end.

**My goal for this post** is to either confirm or eliminate a theory that my misuse of the HttpClient API could lead to memory issues in Solr. I would think that it could (and will) lead to issues in my application, but not the server I am connecting to.

Solr has been throwing these exceptions overnight, after a period of heavy usage from my application, not during a period of heavy usage. If it is not somehow related to lingering connections, I'm not quite sure where to look next. The Tomcat instance Solr runs in is already allocated 3.5 GB of max heap space (-Xmx), so I doubt that it simply needs more. Any help to narrow down my efforts would be great.

My instance of HttpClient looks something like this:

```
SystemDefaultHttpClient httpClient = new SystemDefaultHttpClient();
httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"));
PoolingClientConnectionManager cm = 
    (PoolingClientConnectionManager) httpClient.getConnectionManager();
cm.setMaxTotal(200);
HttpHost localhost = new HttpHost("localhost", 8100);
cm.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(localhost), 200);
```

My SolrServer instance looks something like this:

```
SolrServer ss = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8100/solr/core1", httpClient);
```

My Solr HTTP requests look something like this:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8100/solr/core1/select");
List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("q", "query terms"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fl", "field1,field2,field3"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

InputStream inputStream=null;
try {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    inputStream = entity.getContent();
    //do something with the response body
} finally {
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the logs? Anything suspicious over there?

Comment: Is the webapp just queying or does it also send documents for indexing?

Comment: Nothing suspicious in the Solr logs. The exception is thrown most often when trying to commit with a"cannot commit" message. My web app both indexes and queries with Solrj and also queries via http api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OutOfMemoryErrors in Solr are not caused by any connection management deficiencies that I may or may not have in my application. It appears my problem is somewhere in Solr with regards to merging segments and/or garbage collection, in addition to above average usage on an inadequate test server.

Answer (score 0):

Not been in your particular scenario , but mine was much alike are you receving illegalstate exeptions as well .

Please can you provide number of queries , no of documents , number of threads in tomcat
and garbage collection parameters in tomcat

you can also try to increase the number of threads to solve this problem

regards

Rajat

Comment: I'm working on memory, but I think my GC params are UseParallelGC with 10 threads. Solr has approx 200,000 documents in 1 core, 2.5 million documents in a 2nd core that is replicated to a 3rd core for querying. Solr's tomcat has a max thread setting of 300, but I can't imagine there have been more than 20 or 30 active at once in our testing scenarios. I don't have a good guess for number of queries. My testing scenario involves indexing and querying on core 1 and just querying on core 3, which is configured with large caches.